# LINQ strong typing

Tags: vb.net, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I know LINQ is supposed to automatically return strongly typed result sets.  When I attach an ObjectDataSource to a LINQ based method however (with no explicit return type), I don't get access to any of the columns defined in the LINQ.

Example method:

```
   <System.ComponentModel.DataObjectMethod(ComponentModel.DataObjectMethodType.Select)> _
    Public Function GetMarketClusterList() As IEnumerable(Of MarketCluster)
        Return From d In db.tblMarkets
               Select New MarketCluster With {.MarketCluster = d.MarketCluster}
               Distinct
    End Function

    Public Class MarketCluster
        Public MarketCluster As String
    End Class
```

**EDIT**
I changed my code to use an explicit type and select into that.  At least now I know the return type, but it doesn't help with the original problem.  Even weirder, I found with the debugger that if I do

<%# Eval("MarketCluser") %> it fails and says "A field or property with the name MarketCluster was not found on the selected data source", but if I do <% Container.DataItem.MarketCluser %> it works fine!

Comment: Why don't you specify the return type of your function?

Comment: I don't think the Distinct will do what you expect. It will compare the references not the string you set .MarketCluster to and since you are constructing all the objects in the list you're calling distinct on the references are all already unique

Comment: why not simply return an IEnumerable(Of String) instead of introducing a wrapper class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message said the exact error, I just missed it.  When it said could not find a "property", it meant class member called "Property".  I changed my code to this and now it works perfectly.

```
Private _MarketCluster As String
Public Property MarketCluster As String
    Get
       Return _MarketCluster
    End Get
    Set(value As String)
       _MarketCluster = value
    End Set
End Property
```

Answer (score 2):

Simply specify the return type:

```
Public Function GetMarketClusterList() As IEnumerable(Of MarketCluster)
    Return From d In db.tblMarkets
           Select d.MarketCluster
           Distinct
End Function
```

(or use `IQueryable` instead of `IEnumerable`)

... assuming the type of `d.MarketCluster` is `MarketCluster`.

The return type is *required* if `Option Strict` is on anyway... which suggests that you've probably *not* got it on. I would strongly suggest that you enable `Option Strict` for your project whether you're using LINQ or not, unless you specifically *need* late binding etc (in which case I'd try to restrict it to only those places that need it).

Comment: The return type is IEnumerable(Of <anonymous type>), not MarketCluster.  How do I change it?

Comment: @just.another.programmer: Why would it be of an anonymous type? You're just selecting `d.MarketCluster`... if your real query has a select statement with an anonymous type, you should have said so - because at that point you *can't* declare it as a return type in a strongly-typed way.

Comment: The query I posted is the real exact query I have in my code.  When I use intellisense to check the return type, it tells me it's an IQueryable(Of <anonymous type>).

Comment: @just.another.programmer: I'm not a VB programmer, and I know sometimes VB *does* introduce anonymous types less visibly than C#... but I can't see why it would do so here. What happens if you remove the Distinct (just for the sake of experimentation)? What is the type of `d.MarketCluster` here? (What happens when you hover over it?)

Comment: It's a string.  I just made it an explicit type (see question edit) to avoid this part of the issue, still can't use it properly in my ODS.

Comment: @just.another.programmer: If it's a string, you should just be able to make it `IQuerable(Of String)`. Leaving aside the ODS aspect, what happens if you just change the function to have a return type of `IQueryable(Of String)` and turn Option Strict On? Does it compile? If so, it's a different problem, and one with how you're using the ODS rather than with the ODS itself, I suspect.